# Append a new column at end of csv file using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I am parsing few logs where I extract a single column from each log. I need to keep on appending them to a csv file.

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific and show us your code, your inputs and your expected results.

Comment: Fazlin, let me explain with examples. Log1.txt has column 1, column 2, column 3. I need to redirect them to a csv file using shell script. My csv file should contain all the columns intact.

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details. Show us your example log1.txt and csv file contents before and after script execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat foo.txt 
foo0
foo1
foo2
$ cat bar.txt 
bar0
bar1
bar2
$ cat qux.txt 
qux0
qux1
qux2
```

You can use `paste` and `-d`elimit with `,`:

```
$ paste -d, foo.txt bar.txt qux.txt
foo0,bar0,qux0
foo1,bar1,qux1
foo2,bar2,qux2
$
```

Comment: @Murali, not a problem, happy to help. `paste` is one of those under-represented narrow-purpose tools that gets forgotten occasionally.